# Knowing Privilege rights on a file in Linux

Tags: linux

i wanted to know the Read / Write Access on to a file , so i did this way

```
ls -l Denem.sh
```

This command displayed

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pavan employee 672 DEC 20  2000 pavan.sh
```

Could anybody please tell me what -rwxr-xr-x  indicates ??
From Wikipedia.com i found that  -rwxr-xr-x  indicates

> -rwxr-xr-x
>   for a regular file whose user class has full permissions and whose group and others classes have only the read and execute permissions.

**Now my  question is** Should we take the middle thing **(-xr-)** into considiration ??

Comment: RTFM: `man 1 ls`

Comment: Be gentle, @larsmans. The OP is clearly a complete Unix newbie. Don't scare him/her away.

Comment: Sorry, but this was the second question by the OP about this very same topic on SO today.

Comment: Ah, well, in that case, you may fire when ready :)

Comment: This seems to me like a question which is mostly about WHAT file permissions are and HOW they work. That's why my answer was so long :)

Answer (score 19):

This string:

```
-rwxr-xr-x
```

Is separated into four sections:

```
-    indicates what kind of file it is
rwx  (first 3) owner permissions
r-x  (second 3) group permissions
r-x  (last 3) other permissions
```

All together, this string is supposed to provide (at a glance) the most important aspects of a file. Namely what it is and who can do what with it.

---

**First Section**

The first character in the string is reserved for the file type. Any regular old file will simply have a `-` in this position. Other include:

```
d directory
p pipe/fifo
l link
c character device file
b block device file
s local domain socket
```

So a pipe might look like this:

```
prwx------ root root filename
```

---

**Second - Third - Fourth Section**

The next 9 bits describe the permissions that everyone has when it comes to this file. There are three types of permissions:

```
r read (opening the file for reading, can't save changes)
w write (change the contents of file)
x execute (run the file, like a script or binary)
```

And there are three groups to which these permissions may be applied to:

```
owner whoever owns the file (as seen by the output of ls -l)
group whoever is part of the group owner of this file
others anyone who doesn't fall in either of the two above categories
```

For example:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pavan employee 672 DEC 20  2000 pavan.sh
pavan is the owner
employee is the group owner name
anyone else falls into "others"
```

Referring to the above example, if we want to make `pavan` have full control over the file, let anyone in the `employee` group to read or execute the file and block all permissions to `others`:

```
-rwxr-x---
```

---

**The numbers**

The reason permissions are sometimes represented with numbers is that it is generally easier to use an octal representation of the 9 bits (I still prefer straight up `rwx`).

To understand what the numbers mean you need to build a table (if you've ever done work with binary this will help):

```
#  r  w  x
0  0  0  0
1  0  0  1
2  0  1  0
3  0  1  1
4  1  0  0
5  1  0  1
6  1  1  0
7  1  1  1
```

You refer to this chart for each set of three bits. For example, if I decide to give the owner of the file complete control (r,w and x), only read for the group and also only read for others:

```
rwx owner corresponds to 7 in the table
r-- group corresponds to 4 in the table
r-- other corresponds to 4 in the table
Therefore my file has permissions 744
```

Comment: But just because a file has 'r' permissions for a user doesn't mean they can read it - they also need to r+x on a directory it is in. The rute (http://linux.2038bug.com/rute-home.html) is an excellent, free, online introduction to Unix (inlcuding file permissions)

Answer (score 7):

Divide it up like this:

```
- rwx r-x r-x
```

It's owner, group, others. So the owner (`pavan`) can read, write, and execute; people in the group `employee` can read and execute, but not write; anyone else can also read and execute but not write.

The `-` in front would be `d` for a directory, `l` for a symbolic link, etc. `man ls`.